# Behavior of mutating STL algorithms acting on sequences of movable but non-copyable objects

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move-semantics, stl-algorithm

If I have a class Foo that is movable but non-copyable and I store it in a std::vector, then would applying an algorithm like partition or sort have any caveats? As part of these algorithms should a correctly implemented no-throw swap guarantee correct behavior?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: `std::sort` requires `RandomAccessIterator`s that are `ValueSwappable` and where `*i` (`i` being such an iterator) is `MoveConstructible`, see [alg.sort]. What should be the problem with a non-existing or non-callable copy constructor? As long as the *called* constructor (for `MoveConstructible`) is the move constructor I don't see any problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I did and encountered some problems. I'm too lazy to pull my code out and post here, but I shall soon.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

With respect to element behavior, both algorithms just require that the iterator can swap elements, meaning that if it's a movable type and the container is implemented correctly, then the behavior will be correct.